# Связи с ArrayDataProvider

Tags: yii2

Собственно вопрос можно ли использовать связные данные при использовании связки ArrayDataProvider и ListView. И если можно то как ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно, вы можете использовать любой [dataprovider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html) для ListView.

Только работая с выводом данных не забывайте что работаете с массивом, а не объектом.
Вот простой пример:

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => [
        ['title' => 'Test'],
        ['title' => 'Test 2']
    ],
]);
```

И вывод этого в ListView:

```
ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return $model['title'];
    }
];
```